# invalid use of '.', ',' '()' in query expression

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2016

I am not able to find the error ....it is stating invalid use of expression

```
       SELECT V_14_15.[MD], V_14_15.[SD],
       V_14_15.[IH], V_14_15.[SD], 
       MASTER.[HD], MASTER.[JD], 
       MASTER.[MI], MASTER.[SB]
       FROM V_14_15, MASTER 
       WHERE V_14_15.[MJ]=MASTER.[MJ] AND
        V_14_15.[SM]=MASTER.[SM] AND
        V_14_15.[M] =MASTER.[M] AND
         V_14_15.[S]=MASTER.[S];
```

Comment: This: `V_14_15. [SM]` is obviously wrong. You can't have a space after a dot in a query like that.

Comment: my code is not having space ....its when i copy pasted here,it created space

Comment: I'd check your code for hidden characters then. Currently, your problem is not reproducible, and when you copy-paste code here spaces shouldn't suddenly appear.

Comment: Should use JOIN clause instead of WHERE in this case. Is this built in Access query builder?

Comment: @June7 i created using sql query in query design.....will try using JOIN....

Comment: why this parameter value dialog appears....Can some one explain the logic....how to remove it....

Answer (score 0):

Try this

SELECT V_14_15.[MD], V_14_15.[SD],V_14_15.[IH], V_14_15.[SD], MASTER.[HD], MASTER.[JD],MASTER.[MI], MASTER.[SB]
FROM V_14_15, MASTER 
INNER JOIN  MASTER ON (V_14_15.MJ=MASTER.MJ) AND (V_14_15.SM=MASTER.SM) AND (V_14_15.M=MASTER.M) AND (V_14_15.S=MASTER.S);